# Closed Subset of $l^{1}$ Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $l^{1}$ be the space of real sequences with the usual metric. Consider the sequence $(x_{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ where we define for $x_{i}$, $x_{i}^{n}=1+\frac{1}{i}$ if $n=i$ and $x_{i}^{n}=0$ otherwise. I want to know if the set $(x_{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is closed or not.

My argument was thinking of showing that any sequence in $(x_{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that converges is ultimately constant (else, we can show that the sequence is not Cauchy, and hence will not be convergent since $l^{1}$ is complete). Then, clearly any convergent sequence from the set will have that its limit belongs to the set (since its constant).

Would my argument be correct? Maybe I'm missing something important.

Comment: Your idea is correct, do you know how to show that?

Comment: Which idea are you referring to? (the argument or the claim?)

Comment: That any subsequence is ultimately constant.

Comment: I was thinking of showing that $d(y_{n},y_{m})=2+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$ if $n \neq m$, which will imply that the sequence is not Cauchy, and thus not convergent. In turn, this is a contradiction and thus the sequence must be constant (and as well, being a sequence of the set $(x_{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ may not be a subsequence as we can take as a sequence $y_{1}=x_{2}$ and $y_{2}=x_{1}$ and so on...).

Comment: Yes, the main point is that $d(y_n, y_m) \ge 2$ for all $n\neq m$, so no subsequence of $\{y_n\}$ would converges (except the constant one).